# Python. Последний максимум

Tags: python, list

Найдите наибольшее значение в списке и индекс последнего элемента, который имеет данное значение за один проход по списку, не модифицируя этот список и не используя дополнительного списка.

Мой код:

```
a = input().split()
print(max(a), a.index(max(a)))
```

Существует проблема, при которой в списке два или более элементов равны максимуму списка. Как получить индекс последнего?

Comment: у вас уже два прохода

Comment: @splash58 я исправлю на переменную как только пойму как получить масимальный индекс

Comment: а вы не думаете, что обычный цикл проще решит проблему?

Comment: `len(a) - a[::-1].index(max(a) - 1`

Comment: но у вас один проход на макс, второй на перевернуть лист, третий на поиск индекса

Comment: я на всякий случай написал код в ответ, пусть полежит :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 1, 0, 4, 5, 0]

i, item = max(enumerate(a), key=lambda pair: (pair[1], pair[0])))
print(item)  # 5 - значение последнего максимума
print(i)  # 6 - индекс последнего максимума
```

При нахождении максимума сравниваем пары индекс-значение, но с помощью key-функции делаем чтобы значение было более приоритетным, чем индекс (просто меняем их местами в паре), в итоге получается что последний максимум "больше", чем все предыдущие (значения элементов одинаковые, но индекс больше).

Comment: Элегантное решение!

Comment: Для таких как я, кто не знает про key :)  - `i, item = max((v,i) for i,v in enumerate(a))`

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = [5,1,3,5]

mv = lst[0]
mi = 0
for i, v in enumerate(lst): 
    # чтобы был последний, достаточно поставить больше или равно
    if v >= mv:
        mi = i
        mv = v
print(mi, mv) # 3,5
```

Comment: Чтобы не было лишней первой проверки: `for i in range(1, len(lst)):` + `v = lst[i]`

Comment: безусловно, согласен, честно говоря, подумал и не стал.

Comment: Просто, с enumerate выглядит проще и красивее, хех :)

Comment: ага, есть такое дело  :)

Comment: Спасибо, пришлось еще помучаться с преобразованием элементов списка к int, но все вышло успешно)