# Python, список, последний максимум

Tags: python

Решаю задачу на coursera:
Найдите наибольшее значение в списке и индекс последнего элемента, который имеет данное значение за один проход по списку, не модифицируя этот список и не используя дополнительного списка.

Выведите два значения. Пробую так:

```
list = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
len = len(list)
pos_max = 0
max_list = list[pos_max]
count = 0
while count < len:
    for i in range(0, len):
        if list[i] >= max_list:
            max_list = list[i]
            pos_max = i
            count += 1
        else:
            count += 1
print(max_list, pos_max)
```

Выдает ошибку тест 6, при этом тест проходится. Значения -9 -7 - 6 Выводит -6, 2

Можете подсказать в чем ошибка?

Comment: вывод правильный. какую ошибку-то выдает? Цикл while count < len: и соответственно строчки count += 1 здесь совершенно ненужны и не приносят никакой пользы.

Comment: есть такой [вопрос уже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1046542/python-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bc)

Comment: у вас почему то есть if else  и в обоих случаях count += 1, может не это причина, но явно ни к чему тут

Comment: count для окончания работы цикла. Такой же вопрос есть, но код там другой,  хочу понять можно ли решить задачу моим способом и что в моем коде не работает. Почему цикл лишний? Как тогда будет осуществляться перебор?

Comment: перебор уже осуществляется в цикле for. Цикл while тут вообще ничего не вносит в код

Comment: Test 6
выдает следующую ошибку. Ок, сейчас попробую убрать

Comment: Убрал while, код остался такой: 'код' list = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
len = len(list)
pos_max = 0
max_list = list[pos_max]
for i in range(0, len):
    if list[i] >= max_list:
        max_list = list[i]
        pos_max = i
print(max_list, pos_max) 'код'

Answer (score 1):

```
l = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(max(l), len(l) - l[::-1].index(max(l)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
max_val = lst[0]
index_max = 0
for ind, val in enumerate(lst):
    if val >= max_val:
        max_val=val
        index_max = ind
print(max_val, index_max)
```